# How i can add an executable file(.exe) to Resources programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**Add an executable file(.exe) to Resources programmatically**

**Visual Studio 2015 - Visual C# - Windows Forms Application - .NET Framework 4.6.1**

What's wrong when i add an executable file(.exe) to resources?

The resource is not displayed with the other resources on the listBox, does not return any error. The names of the resources are loaded correctly in the listbox, the problem if I am not mistaken this when adding the new resource.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add an .exe file to resources
        byte[] xa;

        xa = FileToByteArray(@"C:\Users\" + System.Environment.UserName + @"\Downloads\executable.exe");

        var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(xa);
        using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@".\Resources.resx"))
        {
            resx.AddResource("myExe", xa);
        }
        //
        //Add the name of existing resources into a listBox
        ResourceManager mgr = Resources.ResourceManager;
        ResourceSet set = mgr.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
        foreach (DictionaryEntry o in set){listBox1.Items.Add((string)o.Key);}
        mgr.ReleaseAllResources();
        //
    }

    //Converts a file to a byte array
    public byte[] FileToByteArray(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] buff = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
        buff = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        return buff;
    }
```

**Thank you in advance for your help**

Comment: This does not answer your question, but please check out [File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString` is a bad way to encode executable bytes. If you need to encode them at all (you probably don't -- see below), use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx).
- [`AddResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61fc3tty.aspx) has an overload that takes a byte array. You probably want to use [that one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61fc3tty.aspx) instead of encoding your bytes.
- According to the docs from all the `AddResource` overloads: "The resource is not written until [`Generate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter.generate.aspx) is called." So call that.

Also, note my comment above. Your `FileToByteArray` is just a rewrite of the .NET standard [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx).